# Working with Maps in Facebook Flow

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

In the current React application that I'm building, I'm using Facebook Flow to check the JavaScript code I'm writing.

However, I'm a bit confused about the Objects as maps [as described here.](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/)

I'm having the following dataset:

```
var dataSet : data = {
    translations: {
        TITLE: [
            "sdmk",
            "sdmflk",
            "sdmflk"
        ]
    }
}
```

And the following 2 types:

```
type languageResource = {
    [key: string]: Array<string>;
};

type data = {
    +translations?: Array<languageResource>;
};
```

When I try to access the translations dynamically using this code:

```
var t = dataSet.translations["TITLE"];
```

Flow yields an error:

> 20: var t = dataSet.translations["TITLE"];
>                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ access of computed property/element. Element cannot be accessed with
>    20: var t = dataSet.translations["TITLE"];
>                                     ^^^^^^^ string

Any advice on what's wrong with this piece of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined `translations` as `Array`, therefore the implementation of your object should reflect it

```
var dataSet : data = {
    translations: [
      {
         TITLE: [
            "sdmk",
            "sdmflk",
            "sdmflk"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```